# recaptcha2v с selenium

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

я делаю бота, который автоматически регистрирует аккаунт на одном сайте, делаю всё через selenium на python. При регистрации есть чек-бокс рекапчи. Я нашёл гайды по прохождению рекапчи путём звука, но проблема в том что когда я его запускаю, то при нажатии на кнопку звука в рекапче, пишется вот это сообщение.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-то подсказать как мне обойти это, или вообще рассказать о другом способе прохождения рекапчи. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Один из вариантов - воспользоваться готовыми решениями для данной проблемы. Есть большое количество сайтов, которые предоставляют свое API для решения капч.

Comment: Это да, я тоже их видел, проблема что те сайты, которые я находил платные